# What should be there in the variable REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_REALM, if you use an external docker?

Tags: docker, gitlab, nexus, gitlab-ci, docker-registry

I try configure Gitlab to use an Docker registry

Read article:

[How to setup omnibus installation to use an external Docker registry?](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/25967)

But this articles about native docker registry.

Does anyone have an article on setting configure Gitlab to use an Nexus Docker registry?

```
docker run --rm -it -p 443:5000 --name registry \
  -v /var/docker-registry-data:/var/lib/registry \
  -v /var/docker-registry-certs:/certs \
  -v /etc/gitlab/registry-certs:/etc/gitlab/registry-certs \
  -e REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_REALM="what's supposed to be here?" \
  -e REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_SERVICE=container_registry \
  -e REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_ISSUER=gitlab-issuer \
  -e REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_ROOTCERTBUNDLE=/etc/gitlab/registry-certs/registry-auth.crt \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/fullchain.pem \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/privkey.pem \
  --name docker-registry \
  registry:2
```

What should be there in the variable `REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_REALM`?

Answer (score 1):

To configure the registry to use the token mechanism, you should configure the following options:

auth:
token:
realm: The authentication end point.
service: The service name.
issuer: The issuer of the request, must match the issuer in the authentication service configuration.
rootcertbundle: The certificate bundle which its public key used to sign the token.

So now if we want to run the registry container:

````
-e REGISTRY_STORAGE_FILESYSTEM_ROOTDIRECTORY=/var/lib/registry \
-e REGISTRY_AUTH=token \
-e REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_REALM=https://registry.example.com:5001/auth \
-e REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_SERVICE="Docker registry" \
-e REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_ISSUER="Auth Service" \
-e REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_ROOTCERTBUNDLE=/ssl/server.pem \
-v /root/auth_server/ssl:/ssl \
-v /root/docker_registry/data:/var/lib/registry \
--restart=always \
--name registry registry:2```
````